# ASP MVC TextBoxFor<> somehow remember old entered values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one partial view with two TextBoxFor<>. I notice that when I run my application in browser that text box remembers and display old entered values in text box. I want display clear text box but can't find why this is happening. I have tried with:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

In post method but doesn't solve anything.

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new { @class = "loginUsername", placeholder = "Email" })
            </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "loginPassword", placeholder = "Password", type = "password" })
            </td>
```

Comment: This any help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359029/asp-net-mvc3-partial-view-result-not-updating-editorfor-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be due to a *remember password feature* of your browser being activated which automatically saves all username/password values on the client. You could append the `autocomplete="off"` attribute on your password field to avoid this from happening. This attribute is not standards compliant but most browsers respect it.

Comment: I just figure it now. Auto complete doesn't help me because I still need text input to remember data all I wanted was empty input when user open page. But I just saw that google works the same way. When I sign in chrome ask me to "Save Password" and only when I click that button data stay in text inputs. I just was thinking that this should not work like that.